# CSS3 transition jumpy in Chrome and IE

Tags: css

I was wondering why my CSS transition effect looks great in Firefox and very "jumpy" in IE and Chrome. I'working on this one all day now and I can't see why this is happening. I tried backface-visibillity but that also doesn't work. I'm completly stuck on this one...

What I have is this:

```
<div class="stickyWrap">
  <div id="header">content</div>
   <div id="nav">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.stickyWrap.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.stickyWrap.sticky #header {
    padding: 5px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The best way to explain is to open [this test site](http://theme-department.webshopapp.com/nl/) in FF, Chrome and/or IE. 
Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  Is it about the stickyWrap div?

Comment: I don't see any jumpy animation on the site. Did you fix the issue? What animation should be jumpy?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Did you used Chrome or IE? I did not fix anything yet. I gonna try lomas09' solution.

Comment: I tried on Chrome version 44.0.2403.125 m (64-bit)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: And everything goes smooth?? I'm using the same version... Also 64 bit.

Comment: OK. I see it now. I was scrolling with the bar and didn't see it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to simulate the smoothness of native app animation you can still trick the browser into enabling GPU rendering. Just add this CSS line of code

```
.myAnimatingClass{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: This should be `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`